# 6 mappers created by default in Sqoop?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, hadoop2, mapper, bigdata

I always believed that if you do not specify the `-m` property in a `sqoop import`, by default 4 mappers are created. However, in my case 6 mappers are being created. Can someone explain this ?
This is the sqoop command :

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/cloudera --target-dir hdfsout --split-by employeename  --username root --password XXXXX --table employee
```

employee table has 3 columns . employeename, age and dateofjoining.
In hdfs also, 6 map part files 0001, 0002 .... 0005 are created.

[image]

Comment: what is your configuration for splits?

Comment: @Vishrant found it later that 6 splits are getting created everytime I run it. Yes , I know no. of mappers depend on the no. of input splits but then what is the default value of 4 for ?. I did not specify any configuration as such. It is default.

Comment: check how many blocks are there for your data, number of splits [and thus number of mapper] depends on number of blocks as the relation is one to one.

Comment: If it depends on the no of blocks, what does the default value of 4 mean in case of sqoop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,  splitting on integer column is recommended.

As per [code](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/660f3e8ad07758aabf0a9b6ede3accdfac5fb1be/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/mapreduce/db/TextSplitter.java#L74),

```
LOG.warn("You are strongly encouraged to choose an integral split column.");
```

It is not guaranteed that sqoop will generate the same amount of mappers as mentioned by you  in `-m <number of mappers>`

See [code](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/660f3e8ad07758aabf0a9b6ede3accdfac5fb1be/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/mapreduce/db/TextSplitter.java#L100) for details. Useful part of code:

```
// Use this as a hint. May need an extra task if the size doesn't
// divide cleanly.
int numSplits = ConfigurationHelper.getConfNumMaps(conf);
```

If you use `--verbose` at the end of the query. you will see boundary values on which split is done.

If you split it on integer value, I am sure only 4 mappers will run in this case.

Answer (score 0):

### 4 is the default value for the SUGGESTED number of mappers.

So running a squoop command without suggesting a number of mappers, should be equivalent to running a squoop command with a suggestion of 4 mappers.

However, the suggestion may be ignored, you can already see that the suggestion can be ignored if you do not give a suggestion, but as can be seen [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/45311/sqoop-ignoring-number-of-mappers.html), the suggestion can also be ignored if you *do* specify the number.